# Need to display percentage of the individual bar in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi Need help in displaying total percentage value for each individual bar at the end for the particular bar. I'm not sure how to get this done and where to start to get it. Please give me a suggestion/solution which helps to get the output.

Please take a look at the below image:[image]

```js
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Dec', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'SEP', 'AUG', 'JUL', 'JUN', 'May', 'APR', 'MAR', 'FEB', 'JAN']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
   //labels:{enabled: false},
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },
        legend: {
            reversed: true
        },
  exporting: { enabled: false },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
  colors: ['#00c292', '#fec107', '#ff902d', '#dd1936'],
        series: [{
            name: '100%',
            data: [0, 18, 15, 17, 16, 17, 18, 21, 21, 19, 15, 14]
        }, {
            name: '90%',
            data: [0, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 5, 7, 12]
        }, {
            name: '80%',
            data: [0, 3, 5, 6, 5, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 2]
        }, {
            name: '< 80%',
            data: [0, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 500px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Comment: January will have 4 values, which one do you want to display or you want to display all?

Comment: @void i need to display the percentage as in the above image.

Comment: What are those percentages? Should they be calculated based on the columns?

Comment: @morganfree Yes

Comment: It is not clear for me what the percentage represent. You can use stack label for labelling columns http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/stacklabels-enabled/

Comment: ^Agreed. What is the `84.3%` in your image? Where is it calculated from?